# Highest value of equation "T(C-NT)"

Tags: math, differentiation

Given equation `T(C-NT)`. Here given value of `C` & `N`. I have to find the minimum value of T so that given equation value is maximazied.

My approach:

Let maximum value of equation is `y`. So, `y = T(C-NT)
y = T C - T^2 N`

If we differentiate this equation with respect to `T` then we got `0 = C - 2NT`.

So, we can write `T = C/(2N)`.

But I'm getting verdict `Wrong Answer`.

Comment: Explain why this is a C++ question.

Comment: It is math question, but i implement it with C++. So, I thought it's related to C++. Should I remove C++ tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let highest value of the equation is `x`.
So, `x = T(C-NT)`
If we simplify this equation `x = TC-NT^2`
Which is simply a inverted `U` curve. We have to find the highest value of `T` at which point the gradient equal to zero.

If we differentiate this equation with respect to `T` then,
    `0 = C-2NT`.
So,    `T = C/(2N)`

But this value of `T` isn't correct answer. This value of `T` `says optimal value of T` must be equal or greater than this value.

So, we have to increment this value by 1 and check if we can get greater value of the equation.